# Divide line into 3 segments of infinite length

Tags: geometry, divisibility, infinity

Is it possible to divide line (I mean line of infinite length, $[-\infty, +\infty]$) into a three segments of infinite length? My common sense says it's not possible, because every 2 points define segment of finite length, but am I right?

Comment: Is each part required to be a single interval?

Comment: You have to add if your are refered to segments when you say "parts". If not, you have the (correct!) answer $\Bbb R= A\cup B\cup C$  where $A,B,C$ can be infinite disjoinct sets in infinitely many ways.

Comment: I've edited the question, thank you for remarks!

Comment: you must precise if you are speaking of infinite length or infinite cardinal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.  It is not possible to partition the real line into three non-overlapping infinite intervals.

Suppose we have three such intervals.

The intervals do not overlap, so only one can extend to $-\infty$.  Thus, two of the intervals must have finite left endpoints.  Similarly, only one can extend to $\infty$, so two of the intervals must have finite right endpoints.

By the pigeonhole principle, at least one interval must have both endpoints finite.  That makes it a finite interval, contradicting our assumption.

Therefore, no such intervals can exist.

Comment: This is a proof I've missed, thank you!